# NodeJS Express Api -- calling res.send outside route works but res.status does not work no matter what

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

To keep things clean in my express route page I have a local function that is called in every route and it passes the sql query together with the req and res objects.

This works fine for sending a successful result and calling res.send works.

The problem that I'm having is I can't seem to find a way to get res.status to work and no matter the syntax it simply times-out and gives no error whatsoever in the console OR on the front end.

The tricky thing is, when it's inside the specific route it does work but the error message does not seem to get sent through instead it's just blank body?

```
`async function queryDatabase(queryParam, req, res) {
    try {
        const cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        await cp.connect();
        let result = await cp.request().query(queryParam);
        cp.close();
        res.send(result.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        res.statusMessage = `Database error: ${err}`;
        res.status(520);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Here you just set status not send just use like  res.status(520).send()

Comment: @Devraj Ah, I see, I did not know that as it seemed to have worked in the past when erroring out. This has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.status(520)` only sets the status value in the response object.  It does not actually send the response.  So, to send the response, you have several options.  In the more recent versions of Express, you can use this shortcut:

```
res.sendStatus(520);
```

This will both set the status and send the response.

But, you can also do this in any version of Express:

```
res.status(520).end();
```

Which also sets the status and then sends the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should end your response, use `res.status(520).end()` instead of `res.status(520)`